# Sending data from TIdTCPClient to TServerSocket in FMX is not working for Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe8

I'm using Delphi XE8 trail version for developing application mobile application. Currently I'm facing very critical problem below I have explained clearly.

My Project is divided into two different applications:

**Application A**: This application is developed using Delphi XE8 as VCL application. This application has the TServerSocket. And receives the data using array of bytes. Mostly, this application receives the data as packed record and based on the Message Header the next step will be taken place.

**Application B**: This application is developed using Delphi XE8 as Multi Device mobile application. This application has TIdTCPClient. And sends the data as mentioned below:

```
TSamplePacket = packed record
  strValue: array [0..10] of Char;
end;

Procedure SendData;
var
  SamplePacket: TSamplePacket;
begin
  SamplePacket.strValue := '1000';
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(@SamplePacket, SizeOf(TSamplePacket));
end;
```

And for IdTCPClient, IOHandler is assigned .

*Problem:* When I called SendData procedure in Delphi XE8 Multidevice mobile application it have not received any data in server app and also no exception is raised in client. And I have checked in Windows 7 desktop and also Android mobile Lolipop version mobile. In both device, the client application is not sending the data. And same code worked finely in Delphi XE7 for Windows application and Android KitKat version mobile application. And In Delphi XE8 Multi Device mobile application, I have tried to convert the packed record to TIDBytes. But I don't know how to do this.?

But when I have created Delphi XC8 VCL Application and implemented the same code and the same components and I tried to send the data, it receiving data in the Server application.

And in Delphi XE8 Multidevice mobile application, if I tried to send the text which is shown below:

```
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Writeln('test');
```

And when I used this I can able to receive the data in Server application.

Please provide me any help to  send this buffer data to server socket properly. And Thanks in advance

Comment: Should I need to use TIDTcpServer component  instead of TServerSocket  for Application B (which is having the TServerSocket).

Comment: That would be more sensible, yes.`TServerSocket` and `TClientSocket` are old components, always use Indy.

Comment: TCP is TCP regardless of framework, so you do not NEED `TIdTCPServer`, but it would be recommended. However, there is no overloaded version of `TIdIOHandler.Write()` that accepts a `^TSamplePacket` or a `Pointer` as a parameter value.  That code should not be compiling, let alone running, in desktop or mobile compilers. Unless you wrote a *class helper* that you did not show. You also did not show your `TServerSocket` code, either. To answer your other question, you can convert the packed record to a `TIdBytes` by using Indy's `RawToBytes()` function in the `IdGlobal` unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Application A: This application is developed using Delphi XE8 as VCL application. This application has the TServerSocket.

`TServerSocket` has been deprecated for years, and is no longer installed by default. It is provided only for backwards compatibility with old code. Since you are using Indy anyway, you should consider using `TIdTCPServer` instead.

> IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(@SamplePacket, SizeOf(TSamplePacket));

There is no overloaded version of `TIdIOHandler.Write()` that accepts such parameter values. You need to send the data as a `TIdBytes`:

```
Procedure SendData;
var
  SamplePacket: TSamplePacket;
begin
  SamplePacket.strValue := '1000';
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(RawToBytes(SamplePacket, SizeOf(TSamplePacket)));
end;
```

Or as a `TStream`:

```
Procedure SendData;
var
  SamplePacket: TSamplePacket;
  Strm: TIdMemoryBufferStream;
begin
  SamplePacket.strValue := '1000';
  Strm: TIdMemoryBufferStream.Create(@SamplePacket, SizeOf(TSamplePacket));
  try
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(Strm);
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I have used **RawToBytes**  and send the data. And the data which I have send from Application B (which is having TIDTcpClientSockt)  is received in the Application A (which is having TServerSocket). Thanks a lot Remy.

Comment: I have the record which is shown below.
TSamplePacket = record
  strVal1: array [0..50] of char; 
  strVal2: array [0..50] of char;
end;
When I send this packet there is missing of the end values. How can I able to send the bigger values(like 250 of char)?

Comment: @test12345: The record itself is fine. If you are missing data, then you are not sending and/or receiving it correctly.  Feel free to post a new question about that, and show your actual code on both ends.